# rsync-filter commitable to git

Tags: git, ubuntu, rsync

For a linux server i installed rsync, and I want to exclude some folders. So I added a `.rsync-filter` file to that folder, containing:

```
+ .rsync-filter
- *
```

And when I want to commit this files to my git repo, it doesn't show up at uncommitted changes. What to change, so I can add `.rsync-filter` to my git repo.

Answer (score 1):

If your `.rsync-filter` file is ignored somehow by your .gitignore, you can force the add:

```
git add -f .rsync-filter
```

You can also check why your file would be ignored with [`git check-ignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) (git 1.8.3.3.+):

```
git check-ignore -- .rsync-filter
```